# Changing the wp-config.php broke the site

Tags: wp-config

I added the lines `define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content' );`  and `define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'example/blog/wp-content';);` in my wp-config.php and then my site broke. Even some of the widgets on the backend do not appear anymore. I immediately removed the above lines from the `wp-config.php` however that did not change anything.

PLEASE HELP

Comment: What is your URL?

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo but you have a syntax error in your above define for the `WP_CONTENT_URL` it should be: `define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'example/blog/wp-content');`

Comment: A good approach is also to always to backup your configuration files.

Comment: I had added only above 2 lines. I removed them immediately. However, the site is still down and even many of the widgets have disappeared. How can that happen?

Comment: Most specifically i was using the widgetkit for wordpress. All the places where that was used have disappeared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're some things you should *not* play around with, until you really know core inside out and one of those things are the Path constants that *can* be set in your `wp-config.php`.

Here's how I do it. Note, that it's uncommented, so it doesn't trigger and WP uses its default.

```
# define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR_NAME',    'wp-content' );
# define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR',         ABSPATH.WP_CONTENT_DIR_NAME );
# define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL',         WP_SITEURL.WP_CONTENT_DIR_NAME );
```

There're dozens of things you shouldn't touch in there, but Path constants and the Proxy settings are those that can get broken most easily. WP uses for nearly everything a default and you should simply let it do its job. Aside from having nothing from a dir name change (maybe security through obscurity) it will let a lot of plugins break that don't consider those things.

Comment: I can see all my plugins on the backend wp-content/plugins folder. But somehow the path got changed and even after deleting those define('WP_CONTENT_DIR','') and define('WP_CONTENT_URL','') lines. My site still cannot pick up those plugins :(

Maybe it got cached? My wp-config.php is now the same as how it was before i made any change. How can I get my plugins to get detected?

Comment: @user544079 - your problem has [deeper roots](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13707574/1287812). I think you should address that... Have you followed [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)?

Comment: Turn off all plugins, switch to the default theme. See if it still happens.

Comment: Now my site has gone all blank and I just get a white page. I tried to turn on error reporting by including error_reporting(E_ALL);
// OR
error_reporting(-1);
// OR
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); inside wp-config.php as i do not have access to php.ini.  How can I fix the white screen?

Comment: The white screen means, that you got _no_ error reporting. Turn on _everything_, as [I show in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/4063197). And I guess you're developing on a remote server... oh, my... Don't do this. Test stuff in local, then go to stage and finally to production. That's what MAMP/XAMPP and such are for. Btw: You can still access the DB? Then revert (via PhpMyAdmin) to _no_ active plugins and the Twenty* theme.